# MS Access person age at quarter start

Tags: ms-access

I have a table (Service_records) that contains the following fields;

Customer ID
Year
Quarter (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
Service
Cost

There is also a table (Customer_records) with the customer personal details e.g. name and DoB linked by Customer ID to the above table in the subsequent query).

I also have a table with a list of financial years (Financial_years) e.g.

2015/16
2016/17
2017/18

I have created a simple form that has a combo box that will display the financial year and then a button to open a query.

The query currently is a CrossTab query with all the above tables, it shows the Service as a Row and Quarter as Columns like

-------------Q1----Q2---Q3---Q4
Service1|
Service2|
Service3|

What I would like to do is to count the number of customer IDs, who received a service, who were 30-35 years old during that quarter (>30 on first day of the Quarter) for the chosen year, our quarters run Q1-Apr-June, Q2-July-Sep, Q3-Sep-Dec, Q4 Jan-Mar.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need a function to correctly calculate the age in full years like this:

```
Public Function Years( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased step wise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2007-11-13. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a full 12 months period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -intYears, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of years as count of full 12 months periods.
  Years = intYears - intDiff

End Function
```

Then create a function to calculate the start date of your quarters, for example:

```
Public Function CalendarQuarterStart( _
    ByVal FinancialYear As String, _
    ByVal FinancialQuarter As String) _
    As Date

    Dim CalendarYear As Integer
    Dim CalendarMonth As Integer
    Dim DateStart As Date

    CalendarYear = Val(FinancialYear) ' "2015/16"
    CalendarMonth = 1 + 3 * Right(FinancialQuarter, 1)   ' "Q3"

    DateStart = DateSerial(CalendarYear, CalendarMonth, 1)

    CalendarQuarterStart = DateStart

End Function
```

Thus, in your query:

```
Age: Years([DateOfBirth], CalendarQuarterStart([FinancialYear],[FinancialQuarter]))
```

Comment: I tried this and it almost works but when you get to Q4 of a year the age goes down a year compared to Q2 Q3 Q4. E.g with a Dob of 1/3/1980 and the selected year as 2016-17 I get age at Q1 = 36, Q2=36, Q3=36, Q4(2017)=35.

Comment: Yes, I got something mixed up. Corrected - see edited answer.